# inflate menu in CollapsingToolbarLayout issue

Tags: android, androiddesignsupport

I am using the design support library`s CollapsingToolbarLayout.My issue is i am not able to inflate the menu action icon in toolbar. I am using the below code to create CollapsingToolbarLayout.

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="240dp">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:expandedTitleMarginBottom="32dp"
        app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
        app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/profile_image"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />
        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>


</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

In Fragment i use

```
 @Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_emp_details, menu);
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu,inflater);
}
```

and `setHasOptionsMenu(true);`

Comment: What is the issue? Any stack trace?

Comment: @Marko i want to use Action icon in toolbar of my fragment.The problem is it is not showing in the toolbar.

Comment: Have you set your Toolbar with `setSupportActionBar(toolbar);`?

Comment: Could you provide the entire code of your layout plus fragment and activity implementations?

Answer (score 12):

There are two ways to do it:
First you need to tell the `Activity` that the `Toolbar` your using is `Action Bar` by using: `setSupportActionBar(toolbar)`

Else (I recommend):

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
toolbar.inflateMenu(R.menu.your_menu_items);
toolbar.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new Toolbar.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem menuItem) {
            TODO: Write your logic here
        }
});
```

Answer (score 4):

I believe when you say "Action icon in toolbar" you mean the `UP` action on the left-hand side of the toolbar.

If you mean the right-hand side menu with the 3-dots icon, @Janhavi answer is correct. If you mean the `UP` icon on the left-hand side, read below:

You just need to configure it on the toolbar after you inflate the layout, like the following code:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView (LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
// inflate your view normally
View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_layout, container, false);

// configure your views
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar)root.findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.icon);
toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
    @Override public void onClick(View v){
        // TODO: code your UP navigation here
        // probably: getFragmentManager().popBackStack ?
    }
});

// return the view
return root;
}
```

the icon you can download from here: https://www.google.com/design/icons/