# Toolbar/ActionBar menu items not clickable unless showAsAction is Never

Tags: android, android-layout, android-actionbar, toolbar, menuitem

I am having a weird experience with android. I have ToolBar (inside a CollapsingToolbarLayout)

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

And here is the menu file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>     
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"     
      xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
         <item android:id="@+id/action_share"
               android:title="@string/share_action"     
          android:orderInCategory="100"     
          app:showAsAction="never"
               android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_share"     

app:actionProviderClass="android.support.v7.widget.ShareActionProvider"/>          
    <item android:id="@+id/action_browser"     
          android:title="View in browser"
               app:showAsAction="never"/>
     </menu>
```

Here is the Java code

```
@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
        Log.d(TAG,"menu clicked");
        switch (item.getItemId()){
            case R.id.action_share:
                Log.d(TAG,"share action selected");
                if(null != shareActionProvider){
                    Log.d(TAG,"shareActionProvider not null");
                    Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                    shareIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_DOCUMENT);
                    shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
                    shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, url));
                    shareActionProvider.setShareIntent(shareIntent);
                }
                break;
            case R.id.action_browser:
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                intent.setData(Uri.parse(url));
                startActivity(intent);
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

So the case `R.id.action_share` is not seen or clickable.

The share item is onlick clickable when it is set `app:showAsAction="never"`  but if I do `app:showAsAction="always"`  it is not clickable. Any ideas how I can fix this?

Comment: so I tried adding/removing `category`, but nothing works so far.

Answer (score 1):

The toolbar has a separate menu item click listener that you can register with

```
public void setOnMenuItemClickListener (Toolbar.OnMenuItemClickListener listener)
```

the callback gives you a `MenuItem` object that you can use to check which item was clicked. [Here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toolbar.OnMenuItemClickListener.html) you can find the documentation.

E.g. you call `setSupportActionBar(tb);` you won't need `tb.inflateMenu(R.menu.menu);`

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Toolbar tb = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.my_awesome_toolbar);
    //setSupportActionBar(tb);
    tb.inflateMenu(R.menu.menu);
    tb.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new Toolbar.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
            Log.i(getClass().getSimpleName(), " " + item.getItemId());
            return false;
        }
    });

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

Comment: Do I still inflate the menu per normal or is there a toolbar way of doing that too? I ask because it is still not working.

Comment: I would give [inflateMenu](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toolbar.html#inflateMenu(int)) a try

Comment: If I use `toolbar.inflateMenu` then the menu is not visible at all: whether I do it before or after `setSupportActionBar(toolbar)`

Comment: it shouldn't matter. Did your remove onCreateOptionsMenu ?

Comment: If I remove it, then the menu is not visible at all, if I leave it, then it does not matter whether I use `toolbar.inflateMenu` it is still visible. **But** in either case, the item is still not clickable.

Comment: I had just recently tried that based on the answers here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31746644/inflate-menu-in-collapsingtoolbarlayout-issue still same problem.